# Node.js is not catching imap error, how to catch it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I am creating an app that will auth user input. problem is that when the user input is wrong error is not caught and my app is crashing.

If i put

```js
throw new Error("dasdas");
```

That error is caught but IMAP errors are not.

```js
try {
  var imap = new Imap({
    user: email,
    password: password,
    host: "mail.metropolitan.ac.rs",
    port: 993,
    tls: true,
  });
  imap.connect();
  res.status(201).json({ success: true, person: email });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return res.status(400).json({ success: false, msg: "data is wrong" });
}
```

Comment: What errors are not being caught? How do you know they're not caught? From looking at [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap#examples), the constructor and `connect()` don't throw any errors

Comment: For example: If email and password is wrong, i get error: "Error: LOGIN failed" and server is crashed.

Comment: What does `imap.connect()` do? Does it actually throw an exception? I bet it's returning a promise that it'll reject later.

Comment: The docs say you should use `imap.once("error", err => { ... })` to handle errors. Are you reading the docs?

Comment: It's working, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the documentation you need to register the error listener before connecting to the server like this as the error is emitted as an event and not thrown as a normal error would be

```js
imap.once('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

(This needs to be done before connect()) you can read about this behaviour on [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap) page

Comment: Yes i confirm that you need to call imap.connect() before setup listeners